# how to play sound in Ubuntu with PyQt4?

Tags: sound, pyqt

It's a big mess. I chose to write my app with Qt (PyQt4) because it should work with Windows and Linux. First, in Windows I used QSound, it worked, but not under Ubuntu. So I switched to QtMultimedia, much uglier and more complicated code than QSound, and yet again it is not working under Ubuntu!

How do I get sound in Ubuntu? It CAN'T be that hard, doesn't it??

Please name a working module or give any general tips.

Comment: Do you have a post of the code that fails for you on Ubuntu?  What distribution version are you running, with which version of qt, with which version of pyqt?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu Saucy daily (thats not the problem), installed Idle3 out of the packages, and pyqt is version 4 as you can read in my question. In the meantime i found it working with phonon, now have to check if this works in Windows...

Comment: Just noting since we heard "as you can read in my question".  PyQt4 isn't necessarily being updated to Qt5 (although basic support is planned), but as far as I know, Qt5 is the default Qt for latest Ubuntu.  There was a reason I asked for specificity beyond a general package name.

Comment: Hm yeah i understand, didn't want to step on your feet. Sorry for that. I am not sure about the version of Qt, because I just installed Idle3.

Comment: Okay.  Also, Saucy doesn't go stable until October.  Alpha/Beta release questions are off-topic.

Comment: Aha, okay. So now under Ubuntu I got it working with Phonon. It's okay then, thank you anyway! Great community here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2171346/2557231

> As alex said, Phonon looks like your best bet because you can use it
>   with Pyqt. You can find lots of examples of using phonon using google.
>   This one, http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=84275, for
>   example is a command line tool to play audio using phonon. You might
>   also want to take a look at the QSound class. QAudioInput looks
>   interesting for adding support for a mike.
>
> I hope this helps.
>
> P.S.:
>
> 1. The riverbank site does mention the phonon module :)
> 2. I found a question on using Phonon + Pyqt -
>      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083118/play-mp3-using-python-pyqt-and-phonon

Comment: Yes, phonon is the way to go here.